# Ahlfors Riemann sphere to stereographic projection

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, proof-explanation

In the chapter on complex numbers, Ahlfors makes a link between associating a point on the sphere to stereographic projection.  However I'm unsure of the details of how he does this.  He writes that by writing $z=x+iy$ we have
$$x:y:-1=x_1:x_2:x_3-1$$
as far as I can tell, these are homogeneous coordinates, so I think what this means are that the two descriptions are describing the same point.  He then says that

> this means that the points $(x,y,0),(x_1,x_2,x_3),and(0,0,1)$ are in a straight line.

I don't see how he gets to this conclusion, particularly because $(0,0,1)$ would give homogeneous coordinates of $(0:0:0)$ which aren't associated with any number.  So

1. Is my interpretation of the equation correct?  Is it just saying the description on the sphere and on the $x-y$ plane the same?
2. How does that lead to the conclusion that they are on the same line, and why isn't $(0,0,1)$ forbidden by the rules of homogeneous coordinates?

Comment: If it helps, it looks like Ahlfors has translated by $(0, 0, 1)$, i.e., is using "homogeneous coordinates" with the origin at $(0, 0, 1)$.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know "homogeneous coordinates".

In Alfhors's text, we have
$$z=x+iy=\frac{x_1+ix_2}{1-x_3}$$

Hence $x=\frac{x_1}{1-x_3}$ , $y=\frac{x_2}{1-x_3}$ and

\begin{align} x:y:-1 
  &=\frac{x_1}{1-x_3}:\frac{x_2}{1-x_3}:-1\\& =x_1:x_2:x_3-1
\end{align}

Now let $N=(0,0,1), B=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $C=(x,y,0)$

Then $\overrightarrow{NC}=(x,y,-1)$ and $\overrightarrow{NB}=(x_1,x_2,x_3-1)$.

Thus $\overrightarrow{NB}=\alpha \overrightarrow{NC}$ for some $\alpha \in \Bbb R$.

$N, B, C$ are therefore collinear.

[image]

Ahlfors used stereographic projection to establish a one-one correspondence between the surface of the unit sphere and the complex plane.

$(0,0,1)$ is mapped to the complex number $\infty$.